# Update view count every page view (even refresh) [Wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, view, refresh

I have the following piece of code in single.php:

```
if ( is_single() ){
    global $post;
    $count_post = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_views_count', true) );
    if( $count_post == ''){
        $count_post = 1;
        add_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_views_count', $count_post);
    }else{
        $count_post = (int)$count_post + 1;
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_views_count', $count_post);
    }
}
```

And in my_content.php this code to display the views:

```
<?php global $post;
$visitor_count = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_views_count', true);
if( $visitor_count == '' ){ $visitor_count = 0; }
if( $visitor_count >= 1000 ){
$visitor_count = round( ($visitor_count/1000), 2 );
$visitor_count = $visitor_count.'k';
} ?>
<p class="meta_do">
<b class="icon-eye"></b>
<?php echo esc_attr($visitor_count); ?> views
</p>
```

Everything works fine for the logged in users, but the problem is it doesn't count the pageviews (or refreshes) of users who are not logged in.

I optimized the code a bit to make it shorter and more readable

```
if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    $count_post = (int)esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_views_count', true ) );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_views_count', ++$count_post );
}
```

my_content.php:

```
<?php
global $post;
$visitor_count = (int)get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_views_count', true );

if ( $visitor_count >= 1000 ) {
    $visitor_count = round( ( $visitor_count / 1000 ), 2 );
    $visitor_count = $visitor_count . 'k';
}
?>
<p class="meta_do">
    <b class="icon-eye"></b>
    <?php echo esc_attr( $visitor_count ); ?> views
</p>
```

Comment: It should work for non logged in users also. did you check in table and make sure user is  viewing post,

Comment: @VidyaL how to check in table to make sure the user is viewing the post? I tried to view the post with incognito or from another browser without being logged in and I can see the post but the view count doesn't update.

Comment: Are you sure `global $post` in the second part is the post you want to see the count of? Check it by dumping the ID. `var_dump($post->ID)`.

Comment: @jrswgtr like I said, if I'm logged in it works perfect, if not... it wont update the counter. =/